# Cin.get() в с++, чтобы не пропадала командная строка

Tags: c++, консоль

Учу плюсы по одной книге, а там автор нигде не вставляет `cin.get()`. А мне приходится, ибо командная строка пропадает. Это связано в версией с++ или с использованием командной строки?

Comment: Под «командной строкой» следует понимать «окно терминала, которое Visual Studio открывает для запуска программы и уничтожает после того, как программа отработала»? Это вообще не фича языка. Попробуйте запускать программу из-под командной строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё нормально, так и должно быть. Коммандная строка после завершения программы должна пропадать. Этого можно избежать как вставляя `cin.get()`, так и средствами IDE. Например, если вы работаете в Visual Studio, то запускайте программы через `Ctrl+F5`, так окно не будет исчезать сразу после завершения программы.

Comment: если у юзера шиндовс, то можно system("pause >> VOID");

Comment: Это создаст в рабочем каталоге файл `VOID`. Вы имели в виду `NUL`?

Comment: да просто прописать system("pause"); без всяких VOID и NULL и все норм будет работать.

Answer (score -2):

Как еще один вариант, можно дописать в конце главной функции return 0;.

Comment: Ну вообще то это нужно писать каждый раз.
Так как стандарт С++ обязует что бы функция "main" возвращала целое число. И если она возвращает "0" то она выполнилась без ошибок.
, а если отличное от нуля то произошла ошибка.
И это ни как не поможет в том что бы консоль не пропадала.